# Fonts of PDF look different in Preview (made in InDesign CS6)

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, pdf, export

I am making an interactive pdf in Indesign CS6, using Quicksand (from Google fonts) as main font. In InDesign, at 100% view, everything looks fine and the text is easy to read. (left text in the image below)

However, when I export to pdf and view it in **Preview**, the text in the pdf looks much lighter and is therefor not so easy to read anymore. (text to the right) In Acrobat and Safari the pdf looks fine.

[image: Difference in fonts after exporting]

Can someone please help me out with this? The pdf is for digital use, so I would prefer to make it look the right way in Preview as well. Is there something that can be done, or should I just take the loss?

Thank you!!

p.s. Here are some try-outs with different types and colours

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello LUZ, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Please be advised that pdf viewers (all of them!) are positively awful at displaying pdfs correctly, especially if those files are actually optimised for print instead of the screen. The result will also vary wildly from viewer to viewer. If you have any questions about GD.SE, have a look at the [help] or feel free to ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site! (En, te zien aan je tekst: welkom! :) )

Comment: Do you have the same effect when the text is 100% black?

Comment: @Vincent
Haha, dankjewel! 
I do want to use the pdf for online viewing only, do you know some tutorials or key words I can google so I can learn to make it look as good as possible in different pdf viewers? I tried to look something up at Lynda.com but realized I don't know what kind of course to look for.

Comment: @MaxWyss Yes I do, I added a picture of this experiment in my question.

Comment: Update: I viewed the pdf in Acrobat and there it looks fine! In Safari as well. But the pdf is intended for digital use; can I do something so that people who will view it in Preview will see it correctly?

Comment: You'll need to ask Apple why Preview fails to render PDFs properly. It's really an issue with that app and you could spend hours trying to reformat so things look correct in Preview.. then they may appear incorrect in other PDF viewers.

Comment: Does the PDF contain any kind of transparency? (This should be marked in InDesign, visible in the Pages panel.) Apple's Preview is horrendously unreliable with that. Try exporting to the lowest PDF version and compare again. The lowest PDF version does not export transparency, it gets all flattened out.

Answer (score 1):

Preview.app uses Apple’s font rendering system. This can be slightly adjusted in Preferences.app, but it is simply going to render differently than in an Adobe product.

If the on-screen appearance of your type is really important, you should probably get a font which is optimized for use on screens.